# Counting occurrences of unique values in a column using sql

Tags: sql

Is there a simple way for counting occurrences of unique values in a column using sql.

for e.g if my column is

```
a
a
b
a
b
c
d
d
a
```

Then the output should be

a  4 
b  2 
c  1 
d  2

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
SELECT ColumnName, COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ColumnName
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`GROUP BY` and `COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

```
SELECT column, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY column
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching and giving some good tought here's the correct query :

```
SELECT SUM(uniqueValues) 
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT values) as uniqueValues 
    FROM tablename GROUP BY values)
```

Comment: Sorry, i tought i was answering another question.

This counts the total of unique values for a colllumn